# Ip Address Owner

Tags: bash, ip

Is there a script or a linux programme that can take an ip address(s) and show the asn number owner.it would really be nice especially if you find an intruder in your system.you can connect the ip address owner directly

Comment: An "intruder" is going to use one of your own IPs. You'll have to think about something else.

Answer (score 2):

Usually there is an *abuse contact* for an IP address range which can be used to report malicious traffic from that IP range.

You can use the `whois` command to obtain that contact.

Example for stackoverflow.com:

```
whois 198.252.206.140 | grep -i abuse
```

Output:

```
OrgAbuseHandle: SYSAD101-ARIN
OrgAbuseName:   Sysadmin Team
OrgAbusePhone:  +1-212-232-8280 
OrgAbuseEmail:  sysadmin-team@stackexchange.com
OrgAbuseRef:    http://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/SYSAD101-ARIN
```

**Tip:**

Try this [google link](https://www.google.de/search?safe=off&client=ubuntu&hs=QQc&channel=fs&q=abuse%20contact%20&oq=abuse%20contact%20&gs_l=serp.3..0i19l2j0i22i30i19l8.498672.503290.0.503703.26.17.6.2.2.0.242.1703.4j9j1.14.0.msedr...0...1c.1.61.serp..4.22.1732.bTCGw93VvAY) to find helpful online tools.